# How to delete from spring boot -REST API /JPA?

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I want to delete an item from table.

Present valuee like below:

```
CatId         CatName
1             Name1
1             Name2
1             Name3
1             ABC1 
1             ABC2
2             Name4
3             Name5
```

Both columns are in same table. How to delete NAME1,NAME2, NAME3 from CatName column where CatId is 1 using spring boot jpa?

Comment: Create a query something like : @Query("delete from Cat b where b.id=1")

Comment: The same I'd contain other value...can't delete based on I'd only. Need I'd along with cat name...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Cat Repository and put this method as follows..

```
@Repository
public interface CatRepository extends JpaRepository<Cat, Integer > {

   List<Cat> findAllByCatIdAndCatNameLike(Integer catId, String catName);

}
```

In your service class create method and put in to following code lines.

```
List<Cat> catList = catRepository.findAllByCatIdAndCatNameLike(1, Name);
catRepository.deleteAll(catList);
```

Comment: While I don't think there's anything wrong with the above, why not make a delete method in the repository with criteria ? `deleteByCatIdAndCatName(Integer catId, String catName);`

Comment: Here one catId can have multiple catName but catName is unique. So, request parameter should be catId & List<String> catName;

Comment: Also, can't use 'Like' as caused similer other catName should be populated.